# What is wrong with my loop statements?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop, scope

I am trying to make a sudoku checker function to see if the entered board is valid. To do this, I would generate a board, and check each individual row, column, and set of 9 squares to see if they each contain the numbers 1-9. If they do not contain each number in that specific region, the function would 
`return false;`

Right now, I'm focusing on checking the rows of the sudoku board. I didn't want to have to input all 9 rows when checking the compiled version, so I am focusing on just a single row right now.

The program checks to see if the row has all 9 numbers in it. If the row is missing one of the numbers (1-9), it will `return false;` to the function and display "Invalid Board!".

However, the program always says that it is a valid board, even if it is missing some of the required numbers.

Here is a copy of my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int DIMEN = 9;

bool is_valid(int []);

int main()
{
    int board[DIMEN];
    cout << "Enter values for array.\n";
    for (int arraynumber = 0; arraynumber < DIMEN; arraynumber++)
    {
        cout << "\nArray [" << arraynumber << "]?   ";
        cin >> board[arraynumber];
    }   
    bool valid = is_valid(board);
    if (valid)
    {
        cout << "\nValid Board!\n";
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "\nInvalid Board!\n";
    }
    return 0;
}

bool is_valid(int isvalid[])
{
    bool check_row = false; 
    //Checks to see if the row has all required numbers
    bool check_number = false;
     //Checks to see if the row contains a specific number in it

        while (!(check_row))
        //While the row doesn't yet have all required numbers in it
        {   
            for (int number = 1; number <= DIMEN; number++)
            // Goes through each # (1-9) to see if the row contains that #
            {
                while (!(check_number))
                //While the row doesn't yet have the number in it
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < DIMEN; i++)
                    //Move across the row from column 0 to 8
                    {
                        if (isvalid[i] == number)
                        /* If the value for this specific element of the array
                        equals the number */
                        {
                            check_number = true;
                            //The row has the number in it
                        }
                    }
                    if (!(check_number))
                    /* If the number was not found in the row by the 
                    end of the for loop */
                    {   return false;
                        //End the program saying the board is invalid
                    }
                }
            }
            check_row = true;
        }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: While I am reading this, a thought came to my mind. Read about Cyclomatic complexity of a program. It is a good habbit to reduce it for a program. You have if in a for in a while in a for in a while. Anyway, it is not your question. I'll see if I can find something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never set `check_number` back to false when you start checking a new number.

Having said that, your code is pretty complex and hard to read. You could do:

```
bool is_valid(int row[])
{
    for(int number = 1; number <= 9; number++)
    {
        bool found = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < DIMEN; i++) {
            found = (row[i] == number);
            if (found) break;
        }
        // We've looked at each spot in the row and not found number
        // so we know the row isn't valid.
        if (!found) return false;
    }
    // If we get here we must have found every number so the row is valid
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function seems unnecessarily complicated. It wasn't clear to me how it is supposed to work. Here's a simplified version that should work.

```
bool is_valid(int board[])
{
   // start with board_state = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
   // if the board is valid, we will end up with 
   // board_state = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
   int board_state[DIMEN] = {0};
   for ( int i = 0; i < DIMEN; ++i )
   {
      int n = board[i];
      ++board_state[n-1];
   }

   for ( int i = 0; i < DIMEN; ++i )
   {
      if ( board_state[i] != 1 )
      {
         return false;
      }
   }

   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this:

```
 if (isvalid[i] == number)
                    /* If the value for this specific element of the array
                    equals the number */
                    {
                        check_number = true;
                        //The row has the number in it
                    }
```

Once you make this true, it will be true forever in that function.

Hence if you find a number you return true!

**Note:**
When I did a Sudoku before I did this:

- created a short, *x*, that's 16 bits, set it to 0
- When I find a number n, left shift 1 by (n-1)
- Do bitwise or operation: the shifted number | short *x*
- You only have complete row, or column, or square, if the short is 0b111111111, that is 511 decimal or 1FF hex.

That would be a simpler implementation: Loop once to set the bit, then verify once.